# substitute short by long command forms from history on VimLeavePre

Tags: command-history

How can I edit the `:` history from a `VimLeavePre` autocmd? I'd like certain abbreviated command forms to be recorded with their long form in the shada file.

I'm in the habit of using both `:tabe {file}` and `:tabedit {file}`, and when typing `:tabe <tab>` I don't get all entries. I'd like to get used to completing with `:tabe<tab>`. In addition, I'd like to make the paths consistent  with `fnamemodify()`.

I use neovim `v0.4.0-391-gb90256e6c`.